# onclick not working with input type=button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to submit my from using js but onclick is not working when used with input type button, even alert in the function is not working....

```html
<input type="button"  value="Register" id="org_reg_submit" class="reg_input" maxlength="100" onclick="org_reg_submit()">
```

```js
function org_reg_submit(){
        alert("hi");
        document.getElementById("org_reg").submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the id of the button or the name of the function and the code works since you cannot have the same name of the button and a function

```html
<script>
  function org_reg_submit(){
        alert("hi");
        document.getElementById("org_reg").submit();
}
</script>
<form id="org_reg" onsubmit="alert('form submitted')">
  <input type="button"  value="Register" id="org_reg_submit_button" class="reg_input" maxlength="100" onclick="org_reg_submit()">
  
</form>
```

Comment: Um the button is org_reg_submit unless someone changed the code... and that would not cause the alert to not show up...

Comment: org_reg is the id of form tag like <form id="org_reg">

Comment: no it refers to form zakaria

Comment: change the ID of the button to something else than the name of the onclick function

Comment: it works thanks coding-dude ,can u explain why it worked when id of button is changed??

Comment: It's because of the way DOM works in the background. The form object will get a member for each inner member (the button) and it will treat the onclick function as a member too, there's a conflict if they have the same name

Comment: @sivasandeepgarapati Check the link in the "This question already has an answer here" box at the top for the correct explanation

Answer (score -2):

For anyone who find this in the future:

- ID not matching in your js function and in your HTML input code. Just
  match them
- Ensure the js code is loaded before the HTML one

;)

Comment: This doesn't explain the second part: "_even alert in the function is not working_"

Comment: Just ensure the js code is loaded before the HTML and it will work.

Comment: No, it won't...

Comment: Sure it does https://jsfiddle.net/6uz9zn7m/

Comment: Your fiddle is invalid and also the HTML. If fixed, the order doesn't matter -> https://jsfiddle.net/6uz9zn7m/1/

Comment: Your code simply doesn't work, the alert isn't showing. My jsfiddle is just an example to show that js code must be loaded before the html one, althoug I know the jsfiddle structure is not being 'well used'.

Comment: Exactly. It doesn't work. But that's your code not mine. I've only moved the parts of your "solution" in the correct places...

Comment: The problem is not my code (which works) but the structure: js code must be loaded before the HTML one. If the OP just keep this in mind in his own code, it will work, regardless the jsfiddle, which is what I pretended to show